# How to show default/alternate image in datalist binded to image control

Tags: c#, image, binding, datalist

Visual studio 2008, Framework 3.5, C#

I have a Datalist control.The Control is binded to Image Control.I am Fetching the Imageurl from database.The database has path of Image like this ~/images/Oneslow008.jpg . but  if the oneslow008.jpg is not Available in Images folder, at the moment it is showing placeholder. Instead, I want to show some default image in case the image is missing.

This  is my Binded Code

`asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="80px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imageUrl1") %>' Width="80px"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a style with a background image like this:

```
.DefaultImage {
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url('Images/COMPUTER1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Make it small enough so when a database image is loaded, it covers up the background image.  Apply the class to the element that displays the image.

Comment: thanks

Sorry, not able to see default image if the image is missing in the directory. it shows alternate text,

I tried following code, 
 <style> 
 .Defaultimg{
     background-position: center center;
     background-image: url('~/images/default.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;

 </style>

I tried 3 more ways, 
1) 
     <div class="Defaultimg"> 
    Datalist control
    </div>

2) 
     <table width="100%" class="Defaultimg">
    Datalist control
    </table>

3)
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  Height="80px"   CssClass="Defaultimg" Width="80px"/><br />

Comment: Try applying it to the container element, the TD, not the image or table.  In any case, if you can't get CSS to display background images, you have other problems.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Wellens

It's Working For me now